# Very small start to MVC refactor in iOS app

Tags: mvc, objective-c, ios

I started to refactor my app to MVC today. I wasted a lot of time because of simple mistakes.

One was I kept trying to access the getter method inside of my custom getter method, which just causes and endless loop of gets.

Even when I figured it out, I repeated this mistake several times. I think it's safe to say I'll never use `self.iVar` inside of it's own getter method ever again.

The thing I sort of want advice on is not just whether I did an ok MVC refactor, but whether I approached things the right way.

One of the things that is really bugging me is my implementation of the `phoneNumbers` getter method in `HALContact`.

When I first created it, my nested for loops in my New View Controller Snippet would run forever and just keep adding the same phone number instead of moving on.

I finally just got frustrated and added the `removeAllObjects` method at the beginning of the `phoneNumbers` getter. As much as it works fine, I'm not sure if that's the way it should be.

And this is how the getter now looks and works fine:

```
- (NSArray *)phoneNumbers {

    // The difference is I remove all of the objects
    if (_phoneNumbers) {
        [_phoneNumbers removeAllObjects];
    }

    if (!_phoneNumbers) {
        //Create _phoneNumbers array
        _phoneNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }

    ABMultiValueRef *phoneNumberRef = ABRecordCopyValue(_contactRef, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    NSString *phoneNumber = [[NSString alloc] init];

    // Make sure multi value ref exists
    if (phoneNumberRef) {
        CFIndex numberOfPhoneNumbers = ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumberRef);

        for (CFIndex i = 0; i < numberOfPhoneNumbers; i++) {
            phoneNumber = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumberRef, i);
            CFStringRef label = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phoneNumberRef, i);
            if (label) {

            [_phoneNumbers addObject:phoneNumber];
                NSLog(@"phoneNumbers count in method: %d", _phoneNumbers.count);
            }
            CFRelease(label);
        }
        CFRelease(phoneNumberRef);
    }
    return _phoneNumbers;
}
```

As far as the general MVC refactor, I threw up all of my new and old files on Pastebin which I will link to in parentheses if you'd rather view them in separate tabs.

[Here's](http://pastebin.com/95YG1Vm8) a snippet of what the View Controller looks like after the refactor. It now uses 2 model classes I made to handle the address book and contacts data:

```
// Instantiate our address book instance
self.addressBook = [[HALAddressBook alloc]init];

// Instantiate our contact instance
self.currentContact = [[HALContact alloc]init];

//Ask for access to Address Book.
BOOL result = [self.addressBook requestAccess];

if (!result) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addFriendsToMediaCaptureSegue" sender:self];
}

if (result) {

    // Loop through all address book contacts
    for (int index = 0; index < self.addressBook.allContacts.count; index++) {

       // Create contactRef from current contact
        self.currentContact.contactRef = (__bridge ABRecordRef)(self.addressBook.allContacts[index]);

      // Loop through all of the current contact's phone numbers
        int index2;
        for (index2 = 0; index2 < self.currentContact.phoneNumbers.count; index2++) {
            if (self.currentContact.firstName) {
                // Add current contact's phone number to array
                [self.potentiaFriendsPhoneNumberArray addObject:self.currentContact.phoneNumbers[index2]];

                // Add current contact's first name to array
                [self.potentiaFriendsNotInParseFirstNamesArray addObject:self.currentContact.firstName];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here are the 2 model classes that I added. One for the address book and one for the contact:

1A. [HALAddressBook header](http://pastebin.com/6HTc71Hu)

1B. [HALAddressBook implementation](http://pastebin.com/2itW22NM)

2A. [HALContact header](http://pastebin.com/3pQ5zTyD)

2B. [HALContact implementation](http://pastebin.com/dkhpkUTB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (_phoneNumbers) {
    [_phoneNumbers removeAllObjects];
}

if (!_phoneNumbers) {
    //Create _phoneNumbers array
    _phoneNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
```

Instead of this, we can replace all these lines with simply:

```
_phoneNumbers = [NSMutableArray array];
```

The best advantage of this, is we don't run into any problems of emptying an array that someone else might have a reference to.  This could cause problems if, for example, you were using the phone numbers array as the data for a table view.  If you all of the sudden removed all the objects, but didn't call `reloadData` on the table view, the next time it tried grabbing a cell, it could be an index out of bounds.

---

```
ABMultiValueRef *phoneNumberRef = ABRecordCopyValue(_contactRef, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

NSString *phoneNumber = [[NSString alloc] init];

// Make sure multi value ref exists
if (phoneNumberRef) {
    CFIndex numberOfPhoneNumbers = ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumberRef);

    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < numberOfPhoneNumbers; i++) {
        phoneNumber = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumberRef, i);
        CFStringRef label = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phoneNumberRef, i);
        if (label) {

        [_phoneNumbers addObject:phoneNumber];
            NSLog(@"phoneNumbers count in method: %d", _phoneNumbers.count);
        }
        CFRelease(label);
    }
    CFRelease(phoneNumberRef);
}
```

I think this section is problematic.  I don't know enough about AddressBook to really tell you for sure, so for now I'm just mentioning it and reserving a section for in the future if I come back and figure out what's wrong with it.  The `CFRelease` on `phoneNumberRef` seems particularly suspicious.

---

```
BOOL result = [self.addressBook requestAccess];

if (!result) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addFriendsToMediaCaptureSegue" sender:self];
}

if (result) {
```

This could and probably should be refactored into:

```
if (![self.addressBook requestAccess]) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addFriendsToMediaCaptureSegue" sender:self];
} else {
```

But... with that said, I did take a look at the `requestAccess` method in the link.  Strictly speaking, it's not in the question and so it's not strictly up for review, but, I'm quite certain it will always return `NO`, as the return is synchronous but the variable being returned is only set in an asynchronous block, and as such, will always be set too late.

---

```
int index2;
for (index2 = 0; index2 < self.currentContact.phoneNumbers.count; index2++) {
    if (self.currentContact.firstName) {
        // Add current contact's phone number to array
        [self.potentiaFriendsPhoneNumberArray addObject:self.currentContact.phoneNumbers[index2]];

        // Add current contact's first name to array
        [self.potentiaFriendsNotInParseFirstNamesArray addObject:self.currentContact.firstName];
    }
}
```

First, we can declare our iterator variable in the for loop initialization statement.  Remember, you did this a few lines up.  But perhaps more importantly, why don't we use a `forin`?

```
for (id phoneNumber in self.currentContact.phoneNumbers) {
    [self.potentialFriendsPhoneNumberArray addObject:phoneNumber];
    [self.potentialFriendsNotInParseFirstNamesArray addObject:self.currentContact.firstName];
}
```

We should also move the `if` check outside the loop so that the entire loop can be circumvented in the case that we're never going to add anything anyway.  Embed the loop within the `if`.

Also, it doesn't make a ton of sense to me for there to be two separate arrays. I understand that you'll want a name associated with all the phone numbers, however it's better to do this with a single array, either by filling it with dictionaries with a key for the phone number and a key for the name, or by creating a custom object that will hold both of these parts.

Comment: Thank you so much for help. I actually went through my code again before seeing your answer and made a ton of changes, including a lot of the ones you listed. I'm going to open a new question this time with much cleaner code and would love your insight on that as well.

Comment: Here's the new refactor, please let me know what you think: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56680/cleaned-up-a-small-mvc-refactor-in-ios-app

Comment: I'll look at it when I can