# Adding friends to address book app

Tags: mvc, objective-c, ios

I have a view controller on my app, where the user is shown a table view. The table view displays their address book contacts and allows the user to select any friends that they would like to invite to the app.

I have 2 model classes: `HALAddressBook` represents the address book, and `HALContact` represents an individual contact.

**HALAddressBook.h:**

```
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>
#import <AddressBook/ABAddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBook/ABPerson.h>

@interface HALAddressBook : NSObject

#pragma mark - Properties
@property NSArray *contacts;

#pragma mark - Instance Methods
- (BOOL)isAccessGranted;

@end
```

**HALAddressBook.m:**

```
#import "HALAddressBook.h"

@implementation HALAddressBook

- (BOOL)isAccessGranted
{

    ABAddressBookRef m_addressbook =  ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

    __block BOOL accessGranted = NO;
    if (ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion != NULL) {
        dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            @autoreleasepool {
                // Write your code here...
                // Fetch data from SQLite DB
            }
        });


        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(m_addressbook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error)
        {
          accessGranted = granted;

          dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
                        });

        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    }

    if (accessGranted) {
        // Access has been granted
       self.contacts = (__bridge NSArray *)(ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(m_addressbook));

        return YES;

    } else {
    // Access has not been granted
    return NO;
    }
}
@end
```

**HALContact.h:**

```
@interface HALContact : NSObject

#pragma mark - Properties
@property NSArray *phoneNumbers;
@property NSString *mainPhoneNumber;
@property NSString *firstName;
@property ABRecordRef contactRef;

#pragma mark - Instance Variables
- (BOOL)hasMultiplePhoneNumbers;

@end
```

**HALContact.m:**

```
#import "HALContact.h"

@interface HALContact ()

@end

@implementation HALContact

- (BOOL)hasMultiplePhoneNumbers
{
    if (self.phoneNumbers.count > 1) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}

@end
```

Both of these model classes are then imported into `HALAddFriendsViewController.m`, and here is how they are used:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewDidAppear:NO];

    // Create an instance of HALAddressBook
    HALAddressBook *addressBook = [[HALAddressBook alloc]init];

    // Ask for access to the user's address book
    BOOL result = [addressBook isAccessGranted];

    if (!result) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addFriendsToMediaCaptureSegue" sender:self];
    }

    // Access has been granted
    // Create array of all address book contacts
    NSArray *contacts = [addressBook contacts];


    // Initialize our friends array
    self.friends = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    // Loop through all of the contacts.
    // Create an instance of HALContact
    // Set the instance's contactRef, firstName and phoneNumbers properties


    for (id currentContact in contacts) {
        // Create an instance of HALContact,
        // set its contactRef property,
        // set its firstName property,
        HALContact *contact = [[HALContact alloc]init];
        contact.contactRef = (__bridge ABRecordRef)(currentContact);
        contact.firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString
                             *)ABRecordCopyValue(contact.contactRef, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

        // If firstName is nil, continue
        if (!contact.firstName) continue;

       // Grab all of the phone number values for this contact
       NSArray *phoneNumberValues =  (__bridge NSArray *)(ABRecordCopyValue(contact.contactRef, kABPersonPhoneProperty));

        // Place a copy of all phone numbers into contact's
        // phoneNumber property
        contact.phoneNumbers = (__bridge NSArray *)(ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues((__bridge ABMultiValueRef)(phoneNumberValues)));


        // Check if the contact has multiple phone numbers
        BOOL result = [contact hasMultiplePhoneNumbers];

        // If contact only has one phone number, then add the
        // number from the phoneNumbers property into the
        // contact's mainPhoneNumber property
        if (!result) {
            contact.mainPhoneNumber = contact.phoneNumbers[0];
            // Add contact to friends array
            [self.friends addObject:contact];
            continue;
        }
            // Loop through the contacts phone numbers
            // and for every phone number, create a copy of the contact
            // and place the current phone number at index in
            // the copy's mainPhoneNumber property.

            // So if "Steve" has 2 phone numbers, he'll be added to our
            // friends array twice, once for each phone number.

            for (int index = 0; index < contact.phoneNumbers.count; index++) {
                HALContact *copyOfContact = [[HALContact alloc]init];
                copyOfContact.mainPhoneNumber = contact.phoneNumbers[index];
                copyOfContact.firstName = contact.firstName;

                // Add copyOfContact to the friends array
                [self.friends addObject:copyOfContact];
            }
    }

    // Set table view's datasource and delegate
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;

    // Reload table view data
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

I am looking for an overall review, and want to see if I am understanding MVC and using it in the correct way.

Some specific things I am also concerned about:

1. Is it ok that I am setting the properties of the `HALContact` instance in my view controller?
2. I was told that `- (BOOL)hasMultiplePhoneNumbers` should also be a property. Is this true? Is it a general best practice to back `BOOL` methods with a `BOOL` property?
3. How is my overall code quality? Everything from comments, style, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Is it ok that I am setting the properties of the HALContact instance in my view controller?**

In general, yes.  In specific, however, I *really* don't like the way `mainPhoneNumber` works.  I also don't like that `phoneNumbers` is an array--it should be either a set (so numbers aren't duplicated) or perhaps a dictionary (so that the numbers could have labels, and you could duplicate a number--but not a label (key)).

Let's start with `mainPhoneNumber` and work with the assumption that `phoneNumbers` will remain an array (which is *okay*, but not necessarily best).

Rather than a separate variable, why don't we just let `mainPhoneNumber` be a convenient way of accessing the first object of the `phoneNumbers` array?

Without changing anything in the header of `HALContact` or anything anywhere that uses `HALContact`, we can do that simply by adding the following two methods to `HALContact.m`:

```
- (void)setMainPhoneNumber:(NSString *)mainPhoneNumber {
    if (![mainPhoneNumber isEqualToString:[self.phoneNumbers firstObject]]) {
        [self.phoneNumbers removeObject:mainPhoneNumber];
        self.phoneNumbers = [@[mainPhoneNumber] arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:self.phoneNumbers];            
    }
}
```

The `removeObject:` method is optional and depends on whether or not you'd want to allow a duplicated number.

```
- (NSString *)mainPhoneNumber {
    return [self.phoneNumbers firstObject];
}
```

Now, there's no longer a backing variable for `mainPhoneNumber`, but we still used it as a property, so it can still be accessed as a property, and we don't have to waste time setting it--it's essentially set automatically when we set the `phoneNumbers` array.

---

> **I was told that - (BOOL)hasMultiplePhoneNumbers should also be a property. Is this true? Is it a general best practice to back BOOL methods with a BOOL property?**

I actually agree that this should probably be a property, HOWEVER, that doesn't necessarily mean there's a backing variable for the property.  I just demonstrated how we can have a `mainPhoneNumber` property without a backing `NSString` variable.

This one is slightly trickier, as you wouldn't want to allow someone to just set this value.

First, declare the property with the `readonly` attribute:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign,readonly) BOOL hasMultiplePhoneNumbers;
```

This means there's no `setter` method created.  You could technically create one.  You can create `readonly` properties that still have a backing variable, and assign it, but the key is no `setter` method is created.

Now, all that's left is overriding the getter--which you've already done.  And because you didn't reference `_hasMultiplePhoneNumbers` in the getter and declared the property as `readonly`, no actual backing variable is declared.

I would though recommend refactoring the getter to look like this:

```
- (BOOL)hasMultiplePhoneNumbers {
    return (self.phoneNumbers.count > 1);
}
```

Any method that takes the form:

```
if (someCondition) {
    return YES;
} else {
    return NO;
}
```

Can always be refactored to simply:

```
return someCondition;
```

---

> **How is my overall code quality? Everything from comments, style, etc.**

```
contact.phoneNumbers[0];
```

When trying to fetch the first object of an array, you should always use the `firstObject` method.  Accessing the first index will crash on an empty array (as well as I think if the array is `nil`), however `firstObject` instead simply returns `nil` and won't crash.  Even if you think you can guarantee the object will never be empty, use `firstObject` for safety.

---

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewDidAppear:NO];
```

I can't think of any good reason to ever send anything but the `animated` variable you were passed when calling to `super` in the view controller life-cycle events.

---

```
for (id currentContact in contacts) {
```

The indentation within the body of this loop seems not quite right.  Double check and probably fix that.

---

```
for (int index = 0; index < contact.phoneNumbers.count; index++) {
    HALContact *copyOfContact = [[HALContact alloc]init];
    copyOfContact.mainPhoneNumber = contact.phoneNumbers[index];
    copyOfContact.firstName = contact.firstName;

    // Add copyOfContact to the friends array
    [self.friends addObject:copyOfContact];
}
```

Let's refactor this to a `forin` loop, which in Objective-C will execute faster than a regular `for` loop generally:

```
for (NSString *phoneNumber in contact.phoneNumbers) {
    HALContact *copyOfContact = [[HALContact alloc] init];
    copyOfContact.mainPhoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    copyOfContact.firstName = contact.firstName;
    [self.friends addObject:copyOfContact];
}
```

---

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

If you've designed your view controller in a XIB or storyboard, you can set these in interface builder (it's a right-click option).  Otherwise, they should be set in `viewDidLoad`.  We don't need to reset this every time the view appears.

---

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

There's nothing wrong with this line... however, ultimately, ALL of this code should probably be in `viewWillAppear:` (unless there's something I'm missing) so that the table view can have it's data right before the view appears and the user doesn't see an empty table for a second before it reloads with its data.

---

And ultimately, all of the code you execute in this method should be its own method actually.

So in the broad scope...

Setting delegates/datasources should either be done through interface builder or in `viewDidLoad`.

All of the rest of the code except the call to `super` and calling `reloadData` on the table view should be moved into a separate method.

`viewWillAppear:` should, in this order:

1. Make a call to `[super viewWillAppear:animated];`
2. Call the method you moved all the contact code into.
3. Call `[self.tableView reloadData];`

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. Thank you for taking the time to review everything and provide detailed changes and insight. Seriously, it is greatly appreciated. It took me a couple minutes to figure out your accessor changes to mainPhoneNumber, but now i get it and really like it.

Comment: Two questions. 1. Why did you not like the original solution I had for mainPhoneNumber? Can you explain to me why yours is better? 2. You said "The removeObject: method is optional and depends on whether or not you'd want to allow a duplicated number." I'm not sure how removeObject takes care of a duplicate when we're creating a new array with that same number on the next line?

Comment: 1. My approach to `mainPhoneNumber` eliminates duplicate data.  2. We're creating a new array with new "main phone number" and the existing array.  If we don't call `removeObject:`, then the `mainPhoneNumber:` we just added might be in there twice (in its original non-front position as well as at the front).  By calling `removeObject:` we eliminate it from the existing array, then recreate the array with the phone number at the first index.

Comment: To elaborate on the first question, there's a problem if we were to change the array of phone numbers but not change the `mainPhoneNumber`.  Your original code means it'd be possible for `mainPhoneNumber` to not be included in the `phoneNumbers` array, which seems odd to me.  Your code also means that someone could have 1 or more phone numbers, but no "main phone number" selected.

Comment: I understand now. "... which seems odd to me." It was a poor solution. The reason I did that was to create a solution for a friend having multiple phone numbers, and making sure there was a cell for each, but your way is much cleaner. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @nhgrif: Why is a `forin` loop generally faster than a regular `for` loop traversing the whole array?

Comment: @GraniteRobert Because of batching.  `forin` loops and other forms of fast enumeration fill up a buffer and grab from the buffer each iteration.  It only sends a message to the collection when the buffer runs out of objects.  Meanwhile, a `for` loop presumes the current object we're working on will be the only object.  It gets to the next iteration and realizes it needs another object, so it sends another message to the collection to get the next object.  This SO answer does a decent job of explaining it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7129920/2792531